# Difference between /usr/bin/login and /usr/bin/bash

Tags: command-line, posix, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between /usr/bin/login and /usr/bin/bash](https://superuser.com/questions/157924/differences-between-usr-bin-login-and-usr-bin-bash)

What is the difference between /usr/bin/login, and /usr/bin/bash? Does the first command something more, or different from what done from the second command?
Is there any reason to choose the first as default shell?

Comment: Some people don't want to use bash as their default shell.

Comment: Those people should be found and re-educated :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - what's wrong with using a program that can't be used as a shell at all due to not being a command line interpreter as ones default shell? :)

Comment: @paxdiablo - on a serious note, people might just prefer tcsh, for example (for a variety of logical and good or sometimes sentimental and subjective reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two very different things, and only commonality is that both usually run at the beginning of loggin in a user and both run a configuration dot-file (.login and .bashrc) that are essencially shell scripts. In addition bash, like many modern shells, also allows you to switch between users, which is one of the main purposes of `login`

In detail:

[login](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_login.htm) is a program used to log in a user, at the end of which the shell (aka command line interpreter) is executed.

login only knows how to do one thing - log in a user (athenticate using username/password, set some environmental variables like TERM and PATH, and execute a couple of on-login admin tasks - see the link for details.

A [unix shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (of which **bash** is an example of) is a command line interpreter coupled with a script interpreter, and its function is to accept input (from the user or supplied programmatically) and execute requested commands.

As far as I'm aware, login can not be used as a shell at all as it has no functionality of a command line interpreter.

Comment: Terminal.app has the setting "Shells open with:" with the option "Default login shell (/usr/bin/login)", and "Command (complete path)" that by default contains "/usr/bin/bash".